# Detect thumb drive(flash drive) when plugged in android via OTG cable

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, usb-drive

I am trying to detect a flash drive plugged in an android tablet. Based on what i've seen is out there, i tried registering a receiver like below but that does not work:

```
 <receiver android:name=".receiver.UsbBroadcastReceiver"
              android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I don't see a security exception either. Is polling the only way?

Comment: Maybe a good place to start would be to look at the Dev Docs. Seems there are other actions associated with this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html What you're looking at is an External Media if I undestand correctly, which is not exactly the same as OTG.

Comment: I need to detect when it is plugged in, The UsbManager is useful only after i know there is something mounted on the USB.

Comment: I'm refering to the actions that are being broadcasted by UsbManager.

Comment: That worked. Thanks for reminding me to read through the docs once in a while :-)

Comment: cool, glad to hear it solved your problem. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a good place to start would be to look at the Dev Docs. Seems there are other actions associated with this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED

What you're looking at is an External Media if I undestand correctly, which is not exactly the same as OTG